# Kli Yakar about Lashon Hara

Tags: lashon-hara-slander

I heard that the Kli Yakar states that the source of the sin of Lashon Hara is the human tendency to focus on the negative side of life. So, naturally, when you focus on the bad side of things, you end up talking negatively also about people and speaking Lashon Hara.

I tried to find where the Kli Yakar brings this idea, but I couldn't. Does anyone know where it is written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the [Kli Yakar in Metzora 14:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Leviticus.14.4.8?lang=he) In the paragraph that starts with ועליהם אמר שלמה -

> כי בעיניו אותו סכלות מעט שהוא רואה בזולתו הוא יקר וכבוד בעיניו יותר מכל חכמה וכבוד שרואה בו עד שזה הסכלות מעט מכריע את כל החכמה והכבוד, ונתן טעם לדבר לפי שלב חכם לימינו, (קהלת י ב) היינו לדון הבריות לכף זכות, כארז"ל (תנחומא שמות יח) אלו מיימינים לזכות כו' ולב כסיל לשמאלו, לדון את הבריות לכף חובה על כן לעולם אינו מספר במעלות זולתו כי אם בגנותו, וטעמו של דבר לפי שגם בדרך שהסכל הולך לבו חסר ואמר לכל סכל הוא, (שם י ג) ר"ל כל הפוסל במומו פוסל (קידושין ע:) וסכל זה החושד בכשרים יודע בעצמו שאותו חסרון ודופי שמטיל בזולתו יש גם בו וגם הוא לבו חסר מן אותו דבר, על כן אמר לכל כי סכל הוא ותולה גם באחרים אותו סכלות שהוא יודע שישנו בו בעצם וראשונה וסובר מאחר שהוא עושה כן כולם עושים כאלה. **אלו הם הזבובים החוקרים תמיד אחר מומי הבריות וחסרונן** כדרך שנאמר (שמות לג ח) והביטו אחרי משה, לפיכך נלקו בצרעת שנקרא ראתן כי כשם שהם בעלי ראתן שרואים ומסתכלים אחרי מומי בני האדם כך נלקו בצרעת שנקרא ראתן